# How to response back to HttpServletRequest (requests) in multi threaded servlet app

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to implement a multi threaded java servlet in which I need to send response of each incoming request, below is my code

```
public class RequestController extends HttpServlet {

    private ExecutorService pool;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        final int NTHREADS = 100;
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
            String msg = br.readLine(), temp;

            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                msg +=  temp;
            }
            br.close();

            if (msg == null) {
                msg = request.getParameter("request");
                if (msg == null) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid request");
                    return;
                }
            }

            System.out.print("Request received: ");
            System.out.println(msg);
            pool.submit(new HandleRequest());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Now problem is in sending response of each request.. I tried to solve this by passing HttpServletResponse  response object in

```
pool.submit(new HandleRequest(response));
```

but this send response only to last request.
How to do it correctly? Please help.

Comment: Basically, don't. Servlets are not intended to be used that way. Scaling for multiple requests will most likely come from the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to archive will not work.

You can use the Async API of the Servlet 3.0 Specification.

Have a look at the [Asynchronus Servlets Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=1437)
how you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with a thread pool, and dispatching requests to it. The application server you are using is already doing this for you - each request is typically processed in a separate thread, in a thread-pool managed by the application server.

So don't use `HandleRequest`, just handle the request in the `processRequest` method, it will be in it's own thread, and won't block other requests.

Comment: I have 8 different types of request and each request communicate with database as well, so thats why I am trying HandleRequest approch.

Comment: It's fine to handle them in some other class, just use the same thread, and not a thread-pool